# How to call function java script when user fill text in input id="value_1" and then press `Enter` on keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

How to call function java script when user fill text in input `id="value_1"` and then press `Enter` on keyboard ?

..............

When user click button `type="button"` it's will call function send_data()

but if user fill text to input `id="value_1"` and press `ENTER` on keyboard, it's not call function `send_data()` , How can i do for call function `send_data()` when user press `ENTER` on keyboard ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function send_data(){
    var value_1 = $('#value_1').val();
    window.location = '/aaa/'+value_2;
    return false;
}
</script>

<form name="f1" method="get" action="">
name : <input type="text" id="value_1" value=""/>
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="send_data()" value="send"/>
```

Comment: Where is 'value_2' variable coming from?

Comment: Arggghhh, dont confuse Java with Javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Use `onsubmit` attribute of form instead

```
<form name="f1" method="get" action="" onsubmit="send_data()">
```

Comment: not work, when i press enter on keyboard, it's will redirect to `http://www.example.com/?value_1=robert`

Comment: @papmooo It did not work because there is an error in your send_data() function. In `window.location = '/aaa/'+value_2;` `value_2` is not defined. Replace it with something else like this `window.location = '/aaa/'+'value_2';` then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onChange if you want to call that function as soon as you change the data in text box

```
    <input type="text" id="value_1" value="" onChange="send_data()"/>
```

if you want to call the function on submit, you can go for either onSubmit

Answer (score 0):

use event listener for the same.

```
document.getElementById("value_1").addEventListener( "keydown", function( e ) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
if ( keyCode === 13 ) {
   // enter pressed
   send_data();
}
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try jQuery, much easy:

```
$(document, "click", "#buttonID"){
var value_1 = $('#value_1').val();
    window.location = '/aaa/'+value_2;
    return false;
}
```

try using jQuery, it's easier and stronger!